# Where to find the paper of G.H. Hardy called "Sur les zéros de la fonction Zeta de Riemann" please?

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta, research

Where to find the paper of G.H. Hardy called "Sur les zéros de la fonction Zeta de Riemann" please?

I've been looking for a while now, and I just don't find it, the basics of the hypothesis !

If anyone can help !

Comment: Perhaps: Hardy, G.H., and J.E. Littlewood. "The zeros of Riemann's Zeta-Function on the critical line." Mathematische Zeitschrift 10 (1921): 283-317.  A scanned image of the paper can viewed [here](http://eudml.org/doc/167645).

Comment: The $1914$ Book "Comptes Rendus de l'académie des Sciences $(158)$" is available at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/ComptesRendusAcademieDesSciences0158/ComptesRendusAcadmieDesSciences-Tome158-Janvier-juin1914#page/n1013/mode/2up) (page $1012$).

Comment: you should better look at Titchmarsh's book chapter 10

Answer (score 4):

The paper is listed in the Journal *Comptes Rendus de l'Académie des Sciences* and the full title of the article is *Sur les zéros de la fonction $\zeta(s)$ de Riemann*. The full reference is

**Hardy G H.** *Sur les zéros de la fonction $\zeta(s)$ de Riemann. Comptes Rendus de l'Académie des Sciences,
1914, 158: 1012-1014*

and you can access this paper on

- [www.academie-sciences.fr](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3111d/f1014.image.r=) with free access.
- EDIT (added another source): thanks to @Raymond Manzoni, who found this resource (also free access) [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/ComptesRendusAcademieDesSciences0158/ComptesRendusAcadmieDesSciences-Tome158-Janvier-juin1914#page/n1013/mode/2up)

Answer (score -1):

this paper is included in book by peter borwein "the riemann hypothesis"

Comment: Can you add more information? This is the answer but too short to be accepted by our community standards. This is more of a comment but since you have less reputation you have added it as a post.